# Gerrit Access git push (Specific group push refs/for/master)

Tags: git, gerrit

I setting Gerrit Access.

I want to set only specific group push refs/for/master.

I setting 
Reference: refs/for/*
push : AGroup  (allow)
push Merge Commit :  Agroup  (allow)

reference: refs/for/master
push : BGroup  (allow)  Exclusive
push Merge Commit :  Bgroup  (allow)  Exclusive

Agroup can push refs/for/*. but master branch only Bgourp can push refs/for/master.
this setting doesn't work.
Agroup people can push refs/for/maser.

And setting 2.
Reference: refs/for/*
push : AGroup  (allow)
push Merge Commit :  Agroup  (allow)

reference: refs/for/master
push : BGroup  (deny)  Exclusive
push Merge Commit :  Bgroup  (deny)  Exclusive
this setting also Agroup people can push refs/for/maser.

please check access~

Comment: Could you attach the access configuration?

Comment: sorry, The answer was late. 
I can't show Inhouse data. But I discoveryed What i was wrong. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference : refs/for/refs/master

Push – B group (allow) (Exclusive)

Push Merge Commit – B group (allow) (Exclusive)

When applying a single branch, We need to add "refs/for/refs/branchName"

Thank you